# Cant get session values in Smarty based JavaScript

Tags: php, smarty

I cant use values stored in session in smarty based JavaScript. Also there is no error but I cant see the values in alert(); here is the snippet.As far as value of "rvalue" is concerned it is present in Session. Here is the snippet.

```
alert("{$smarty.session.rvalue}");
```

i also tried this

```
 var val1="{$smarty.session.rvalue}";
 alert(var1);
```

Comment: Does `rvalue` contain any double-quotes?

Comment: nope it contains numeric value

Comment: Did you actually try `val1 = ...; alert(var1)` or did you actually use a single variable name?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var myVal = "{/literal}{$smarty.session.rvalue}{literal}"; 
alert(myVal);
</script>
{/literal}
```

Hope it helps